# Euclidean distance equivalent

Tags: qgis

I want to determine the location of a dumpsite, determined by the distance from the river. The distance from the river depends on the slope of the landscape in the specific areas. I'm using QGIS 3.20.

I have been having issues running the proximity (Euclidean distance) algorithm where it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't (displaying unexpected results). The times it has seemed to work it has displayed results which I personally suspect not to be correct because when I set the distance to 300 m, the buffer doesn't seem to be 300 m in scale relations).

I would like to know if I can still get correct results by running a buffer while in vector format and then converting the layers to raster for for further processing. I'm using the ESRI: 102562 Hartebeesthoek94 / Lo19 coordinate system. The location I'm working with Stellenbosch, South Africa.

Will it give me the same effect as running a Euclidean distance algorithm while in?

Comment: I've added the location and the coordinate system I'm using.

Comment: Oh is it? What's the difference between Datum and coordinate system? I'm using the projected coordinate system ESRI: 102562 Hartebeesthoek94 / Lo19. If that's there correct term